# How can i show textbox as a Dropdownlist on mouseover

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-plugins

When I hover over a textbox I want it to be displayed as a dropdown list, then after I click it I want it to be displayed as a text box again, how can this be done using jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use [this](http://simpletutorials.com/?path=tutorials/javascript/jquery/ddcombobox).

Answer (score 1):

Try this JqueryUI Autocomplete Box, It can be tweaked as ComboBox as well.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/